# The meaning of ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT in SetConsoleMode flags

Tags: c++, winapi

In windows API, there is SetConsoleMode function.
Among the mode values, I cannot understand the `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` value.
The MSDN document says

`ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT : value (0x0001)` :
 `CTRL+C` is processed by the system and is not placed in the input buffer. If the input buffer is being read by `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole`, other control keys are processed by the system and are not returned in the `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` buffer. If the `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` mode is also enabled, backspace, carriage return, and line feed characters are handled by the system.

Does it mean that when this flag is set, `CTRL+C` is not placed in the input buffer(because it's handled by the system)? or is it otherwise(`CTRL+C` is placed in the input buffer)? The explanation is confusing to me.. Please can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: What is your question? The text clearly says "CTRL+C is **processed by the system** and is **not** placed in the input buffer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will not be put in the input buffer if the `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` flag is set (instead, the system will handle it and send the `SIGINT` signal to the process running in the console).

The same behavior applies to the `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` flag: if it is set, characters like `backspace`, `carriage return` and `line feed` are not put in the input buffer and are handled by the system (erasing characters from the buffer and processing end-of-lines automatically).

Comment: You would expect that unsettling ENABLE_LINE_INPUT and ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT will forward return (/r) character right away, but instead it only passes it after the next keystroke. any idea why?

Comment: Ikanab, did you ever find out why?

Answer (score 0):

`ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` : `value (0x0001)` : `CTRL+C` is processed by the system and is **not placed in the input buffer.**

So basicaly yes, nothing goes into the input buffer, because the special symbols are handled by the system.